# Using union and inner join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the function below, where it merges 2 tables which have the same fields, but different data, and then performs inner joins on some of the fields.
However I am getting a "Incorrect syntax near 'id'" on the id, after UNION ALL. I am struggling to see where my syntax is incorrect.

```
IF (@booking_id is NULL AND @id is NULL)
    BEGIN

    SELECT

    A.id,
    A.booking_id,
    A.todo_type,
    A.due,
    A.urgent,
    A.status,
    A.comment,
    A.create_user,
    A.create_date,
    A.delete_date,
    B.first_name, 
    B.last_name, 
    H.holiday_name, 
    H.date_start,
    H.date_end,
    TT.lookup_desc todo_type_desc,
    TS.lookup_desc status_desc

    FROM

    (
        SELECT
        id, booking_id, todo_type, due, urgent, status, comment, create_user, create_date, delete_date
        FROM
        [TODO]
        UNION ALL
        id, booking_id, todo_type, due, urgent, status, comment, create_user, create_date, delete_date
        FROM
        [TODO_OPERATOR]
    )

    A

    INNER JOIN LOOKUP TT ON A.todo_type=TT.lookup_id
    INNER JOIN LOOKUP TS ON A.status=TS.lookup_id
    INNER JOIN BOOKING B ON A.booking_id=B.booking_id
    INNER JOIN HOLIDAY_REF H ON B.holiday_id=H.holiday_id

    WHERE A.delete_date is NULL and TS.lookup_desc<>'Closed'
    ORDER BY A.create_date
    END
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server code, so I'm adding the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `SELECT` after your `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT
    id, booking_id, todo_type, due, urgent, status, comment, create_user, create_date, delete_date
    FROM
    [TODO]
UNION ALL
SELECT
    id, booking_id, todo_type, due, urgent, status, comment, create_user, create_date, delete_date
    FROM
    [TODO_OPERATOR]
```